# Count frequency of rows based on value

Tags: excel

I have a two columns that looks something like this

```
Sports | Baseball
Sports | Soccer
Clubs  | Chess
Sports | Hockey
Sports | Baseball
Clubs  | Chess
Clubs  | Math
```

What I am trying to do is get two new rows that looks like this:

```
Baseball | 2 | Soccer 1 | Hockey 1 |
Chess    | 2 | Math     |
```

I know I could do this with a COUNTIF but unfortunately the categories in column 2 are quite a few.  Is there any way to count the frequency of a word in a cell range that is dependent on the value of another cell?

I'm using Google Sheets, but I also have Excel and OpenOffice if they offer this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel you can use a pivot table. Three clicks.

1. Insert Pivot Table'
2. Drag Activity to Rows
3. Drag Activity to Values, which, since the values are text, will be a count.

[image]

Edit after comment:

Oh, just drag Type into Columns. Remove totals, if not needed. A few more clicks but still quick.

[image]

Comment: I had to filter it by type one by one to go through and get the totals for each type, but that worked very nicely. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I added a suggestion.